# Change text color of a predefined layout

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, textcolor

I searched everywhere but I cannot find a solution for this simple question: I'm using a predefined layout `R.layout.simple_list_item_1` but I cannot find the way to modify the text color of the TextViews inside it.

Comment: are you using a custom adapter or one of the provided adapters?

Comment: @leibreichb1 a custom one

Comment: ok, then Tanis.7x provided the way to change the text color inside of the getView() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use your own XML layout, you can get the TextView from that layout and set the color on that. The ID of the TextView in `R.layout.simple_list_item_1` is `android.R.id.text1` (see [the source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml) for that layout).

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
tv.setTextColor(getColor(R.color.new_text_color);
```